# Multiple Item carousel (converting JS to TS file)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using a bootstrap carousel to implement it in my angular project And I need to convert my js file to a ts file. I am new to this hence I'm not sure on how to convert and implement it to a ts file. I tried to follow some bootstrap example online but It doesn't seems to work

This is my HTML code:

```
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>

          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




AND TS FILE:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {

// Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
}
```

Comment: As this is jquery code, you can use this code in constructor or in `ngOnInit` and must have imported jquery

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code. This is worked for me and you have to add the only HTML.
HTML Code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide01.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide02.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide03.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide04.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide05.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First check for bootstrap dependency in package.json file in your angular project.
if it is not there then install it by

```
npm i --save bootstrap
```

add in you angular.json file

```
    "styles": [
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        ]
```

After that you need just html code of bootstrap

OR you  can add bootstrap by cdn also

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
```

Than put you bootstrap HTML code in any component of html file

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```